# search across observations for condition and by group SAS

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, do-while, group-by

I have the following dataset:

```
----------
Type  NumDays  Measurement  FLAG
L1        0        0         1
L1       84        4         0
L1      193        5         0
L2        0        0         1
L2       99        8         0
L2      193        9         0
.
.
----------
```

I am trying to keep TWO observations per Type: The first of each Type and the first time that TYPE has a value > 90 for NumDays. The rest I want to delete. So in this case I would want to delete the 2nd and 6th observations.

I was using trying to use data steps via ***set*** and ***"by"*** to use the values of **FIRST.Type** and **LAST.Type** but didn't know how to find the second value and delete other values.  I know this code is not correct but I was trying to think of how to do it correctly via .  Thanks!

```
DATA LABS2; 
 SET LABS; 
 BY TYPE; 
 IF FIRST.TYPE THEN FLAG= 1; 
 ELSE;
 x=0 
 DO WHILE (x=0);
 IF NumDays>90 THEN
 FLAG=2
 ELSE
 <DELETE OBSERVATION>
 end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  I added a sort incase it is not sorted first.  The by statement requires the data to be sorted.  Remember a DATA STEP is nothing but an outer look around the data you are processing.

```
data test;
input Type $ NumDays  Measurement  ;
datalines;
L1        0        0         
L1       84        4         
L1      193        5         
L2        0        0         
L2       99        8         
L2      193        9         
;
run;

/*Sort if unordered*/
proc sort data=test;
by type numdays;
run;

data want;
set test;
by type;
retain keep 0;
if first.type then do;
    keep = 1;
end;
else do;
    if keep = 1 and numdays > 90 then
        keep = 2;
    else 
        delete;
end; 
drop keep;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you-DomPazz!  I will take your comments and make the adjustments to my actual file and see if it works.  Thank you very much for your help.  Still trying to get the basics down.  Much obliged.

Comment: What does the "0" in the [retain keep 0] syntax represent?

Comment: That is the initial value of the variable.  It's not required and this code would work without it.  I put it there out of habit.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it so and a vote up would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
"I didn't check this on SAS just write it on notepad, plz run this and let me know if this doesn;t work" 


data new;
set b;
if first.type then do;
count+1;
output;
return;
end;
if last.type then count=0;
if count < 2;
if numdays >90 and count=1 then do;
count+1;
output;
end;
drop count;
run;
```